# How do I make a polar plot with bars instead of lines?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to identify the colours in an image and represent them as a histogram polar plot. This will allow me to see the colours as they might be shown on a colour wheel. For example, using a blue image, I would expect to see two or three blue bars of different heights and very low quantities of any other colour.

I am not experienced with Python and OpenCV, but this is as far as I have been able to pull together from examples I have found. Process: Read the image, convert to HSV, and display the input file for reference. collect data-calculate histogram; plot on polar axis; show plot.

Read an RGB image, convert to HSV, and plot its colour histogram on a polar axis using python, Matplotlib, Numpy, and OpenCV. I am trying to plot the HSV image but I am not sure if I should only plot the hue (h) channel and not the s and v channels.

**The result I get shows lines. There are no bars, just lines. How do I get the bars to show the colours?**

Input image:

[image: input image]

Current plot:

[image: current plot]

```
[output looks like this showing h colors of image][3]
```

```py
# importing required library of opencv
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# reads an input image and converts from BGR TO HSV COLOUR SPACE
img_input = cv.imread('blue.jpg')
hsv = cv.cvtColor(img_input, cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
h = hsv[:,:,0]

# display input image
cv.imshow("input", img_input)
cv.waitKey(0)
cv.destroyAllWindows()

# plot histogram for hsv image
histg = cv.calcHist([h],[0],None,[256],[0,179])

# Compute pie slices         
N = 20
theta = np.linspace(0.0, 2 * np.pi, N, endpoint=False)
radii = 2
width = 1.5 * np.pi / N
colors = plt.cm.hsv(theta/2/np.pi)
ax = plt.subplot(111, projection='polar')
bars = ax.bar(theta, radii, width=width, bottom=6, color=colors)

# show the histogram of hsv image
plt.plot(histg)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Please visualise your issue by sharing an input image and the current plot!

Comment: Can you maybe find an example on the web of what kind of plot you are trying to re-create? Are you looking for something like [this](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Histograms-of-hue-H-saturation-S-and-value-V-components-of-HDR-left-and-LDR_fig3_334175098)?

Comment: you appear to have copied this code from [the docs](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/pie_and_polar_charts/polar_bar.html) but then you fouled it up by settings `radii = 2` (instead of your histogram values!) and calling `plt.plot(histg)` after that. did you not notice that `ax.bar()` already does the plotting?

Comment: I dont want just a polar plot using bars as in a bar chart. The polar chart I want should show the colors in the image displayed as a polar plot so that if the image is predominately blue the the bar on the polar plot is be mainly blue.  many thanks for your comments regarding radii and was stuck on how to define the hist values for r

Comment: I have added an image showing the type of plot i am trying to achieve